# Can SIEM(Security information and event management) be a data source of Oracle Endeca?

Tags: oracle, endeca

I have a potential customer who wants to have reports about their Information Security coming from SIEM(Security information and event management). I  tried searching for case  studies and articles to see its feasibility but I haven't found one. Can SIEM(Security information and event management) be a data source of Oracle Endeca? I would like to be sure if Endeca can read its format.

Comment: Can you output the information in a format that Endeca can read? There are 70+ products for doing SIEM (according to wikipedia). So without knowing more about the product, the format of the data, or the actual requirement, it is unlikely you'll find the answer you are looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

Endeca supports several delimited file formats, database reads, custom java adapters, and the use of .

Basically if it exports as a file, lives in a database, is a webservice or can be accessed via the web Endeca can use it as a datasource.